# UBER iOS SDK - 401 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

I am following the UBER iOS SDK documentation to integrate uber into my app.

https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate "Ride Request Button" into my app and I copy pasted the example code from the documentation

```
UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] init];
[self view] addSubview:button];
UBSDKRidesClient *ridesClient = [[UBSDKRidesClient alloc] init];
CLLocation *pickupLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 37.787654 longitude: -122.402760];
CLLocation *dropoffLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 37.775200 longitude: -122.417587];
__block UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
builder = [builder setPickupLocation: pickupLocation];
builder = [builder setDropoffLocation: dropoffLocation];
[ridesClient fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation: pickupLocation completion:^(UBSDKUberProduct* _Nullable product, UBSDKResponse* _Nullable response) {
    if (product) {
        builder = [builder setProductID: product.productID];
        button.rideParameters = [builder build];
        [button loadRideInformation];
    }
}];
```

The block UBSDKResponse (response.response) looks as below

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15c6c1eb0> { URL: https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.787654&longitude=-122.40276 } { status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 63;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 01 Sep 2016 21:39:12 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=0";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Uber-App" = "uberex-sandbox, migrator-uberex-sandbox-optimus";
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
```

I have configured the UberClient ID in my app in info.plist file. Not sure what I am missing to get a 401 response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the server token to your Info.plist.

Copy this snippet into your `Info.plist` (right click and select *Open As > Source Code*) and replace `[Your Server Token]` with the Server Token from your [dashboard](/dashboard) (make sure you use the server token corresponding to your client ID).

```
<key>UberServerToken</key>
<string>[Your Server Token]</string>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This part is missing in the Uber Documentation. I added the client id as instructed but not the server token. I tried to pass the token in init method but did't worked. Having it in .plist file worked.